# AWS RDS (PostgreSQL) - Master user lost all privileges after upgrading from v9.6 to v10.6-R1

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, upgrade

I just upgraded my AWS RDS DB instance from Postgresql `v9.6` to `v10.6-R1`. I did this manually using the "Modify" tab in the Databases section under the Dashboard. Immediately afterwards, as the master user, I lost the ability to perform any operations in the `public` schema.

I can connect to the DB without issue, but am seeing this error when I try running a select statement on tables in the public schema: `ERROR:  permission denied for schema public`

It appears that my `rds_superuser` user can't log in anymore (`freetiersuperuser` is the name of my master user, although its name is misleading):

```
master_prod=> \du+
                                                                       List of roles
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         |                          Member of                          | Description
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
 freetiersuperuser | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}                                             |
                   | Password valid until infinity                              |                                                             |
 rds_iam           | Cannot login                                               | {}                                                          |
 rds_password      | Cannot login                                               | {}                                                          |
 rds_replication   | Cannot login                                               | {}                                                          |
 rds_superuser     | Cannot login                                               | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend,rds_replication,rds_password} |
 rdsadmin          | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}                                                          |
                   | Password valid until infinity                              |                                                             |
 rdsrepladmin      | No inheritance, Cannot login, Replication                  | {}                                                          |
```

Additionally, running `ANALYZE VERBOSE;` works, and I can statistic information for my public tables.

If it helps, here are my default access privileges

```
master_prod=> \ddp
         Default access privileges
 Owner | Schema | Type | Access privileges
-------+--------+------+-------------------
(0 rows)
```

Any ideas as to what went wrong or what I can do to fix this? I appreciate all suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe obvious, but have you tried (something like) `GRANT ALL ON public TO freetiersuperuser;`? Not sure of exact syntax - don't have instance to hand! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 5):

So running these two statements resolved my issue (being unable to access anything in the `public` schema):

```
master_prod=> ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER to freetiersuperuser;
ALTER SCHEMA
master_prod=> GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO freetiersuperuser;
GRANT
```

However my `rds_superuser` role's attributes haven't changed, and I would definitely like to understand if this is normal (I don't think it is):

```
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         |                          Member of
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 freetiersuperuser | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
                   | Password valid until infinity                              |
 rds_iam           | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_password      | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_replication   | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rds_superuser     | Cannot login                                               | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend,rds_replication,rds_password}
 rdsadmin          | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}
                   | Password valid until infinity                              |
 rdsrepladmin      | No inheritance, Cannot login, Replication                  | {}
```